# nhibernate : Selecting a static string from DB(Oracle) via NamedParameter or PositionalParameter

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, nhibernate

In order to validate what our oracle database would give us when we feed it with Unicode, we use a simple trick : selecting the string from dual. That runs the Database encoding over the string.

```
select 'Let’s Go' from dual
```

Now I want to implement the very same thing using NHibernate. Merely doing this :

```
string.Format("select '{0}' from dual", text);
```

leaves my code brittle and open to SQL injections, so I'd rather do one of the following:

```
//Version 1 : Named param
IQuery q = this.Session.CreateSQLQuery( "SELECT :staticstring from dual");
q.SetString(":staticstring", text);

// Version 2 : positional param
IQuery q = this.Session.CreateSQLQuery( "SELECT ? from dual");
q.SetString(0, text);
```

Both of the abovementioned ways fail, the param cannot be assigned. I thought this was an issue with putting parameters anywhere before the 'from'-clause, but that turned out to work when I tried without NH. BTW, I tried both Oracle9 and 10 dialect.

Is there any other way I can safely select a static string from my oracle Database using NHibernate 2.1? Florian suggested QueryOver, but that's new in 3.0...

**SOLUTION** (Based on Florian's and Phill's input):

```
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.For<Freetext>()
                           .SetProjection(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String,Projections.Constant(text)))
                           .SetMaxResults( 1 );
        string dbString = crit.GetExecutableCriteria( this.Session ).List < object >()[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a little overkill, but it gets the job done:

```
string text = "Let's go";
var result = session.QueryOver<SomeTable>()
    .Select(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Constant(text)))
    .Take(1)
    .List<object>();

string s = result[0] as string;
```

Comment: Hi Florian, I forgot to say I have to deal with NH 2.1 (Dependencies in referenced assemblies), so QueryOver is not available :(

Comment: @Sebastian - QueryOver is a wrapper around the ICriteria API so you can re-use the projection in a normal query.

Comment: thanks, Phill! Done it now, I've added the solution source code to my question.

Comment: Right now I stumble across long strings, since The you proposed here is (for oracle) SQLified to :  cast( :p0 as NVARCHAR2(255)) - which means that any string longer than 255 letters will be cut off. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Sebastian Edelmeier You could try `NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.GetStringType(2000)` instead of `NHibernateUtil.String`